# Giving inputs to an executed program automatically

Tags: c, bash, command-line, automation

I have a C program that I want to run without having to manually type commands into. I have 4 commands (5 if you count the one to exit the program) that I want given to the program and I don't know where to start. I have seen some stuff like

```
./a.out <<<'name'
```

to pass in a single string but that doesn't quite work for me.
Other issues I have that make this more difficult are that one of the commands will give an output and that output needs to be a part of a later command. If I had access to the source code I could just brute force in some loops and counters so I am trying to get a hold of it but for now I am stuck working without it. I was thinking there was a way to do this with bash scripts but I don't know what that would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In simple cases, bash script is a possibility: run the executable in `coproc` (requires version 4). A short example:

```
#!/bin/bash

coproc ./parrot

echo aaa >&${COPROC[1]}
read result <&${COPROC[0]}
echo $result
echo exit >&${COPROC[1]}
```

with `parrot` (a test executable):

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ true ]; do
  read var
  if [ "$var" = "exit" ]; then exit 0; fi
  echo $var
done
```

For a more serious scenarios, use `expect`.

Comment: This worked for a simple test program I made, but I think I am going to need something a little more involved. Can you give me an example of using except